# Laravel hasManyThrough whereBetween dates

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

I have models for which I get count of views through users. I have set up those models like this:

```
public function views()
{
  return $this->hasManyThrough('App\View', 'App\User');
}
```

In my controller I am sending json data to charts, for each of those model's objects like this:

```
public function barCharts(Request $request){
    $modelName = 'App\\'.$request['option'];
    $model = new $modelName;

    foreach($model->all() as $val){
      $modelViews[$val->name] = $val->views->count();
    }

    return json_encode($modelViews);
  }
```

So for example, my Chain model has 3 chains in DB, and through this function I get number of views for each chain.
That is working all fine, but now I need to get that data, for the time interval which I will get from `$from = $request['from']; $to = $request['to'];`

So, basically, what I would need is something like this:

```
$modelViews[$val->name] = $val->views->whereBetween('created_at', [$from, $to])->count();
```

I am wondering if there is any elegant solution to it and how to go about this or I will have to use some sql query.

**Updated code**

I had to also add a table to whereBetween clause since it was giving me an error:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column
>   'created_at' in where clause is ambiguous

So,this is how it worked in the end for me:

```
foreach($model->all() as $val){
      $modelViews[$val->name] = $val->views()->whereBetween('views.created_at', [$from.' 00:00:00', $to.' 00:00:00'])->count();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have a small typo (or misconception) in your code. You are missing the () after `$val->views`:

```
$modelViews[$val->name] = $val->views()->whereBetween('created_at', [$from, $to])->count();
```

When you are calling ->views Laravel already fetches the data from the database. When you are calling ->views() you get a query object which you can modify further.

You will also have to make sure that your dates are formatted something like this: YYYY-mm-dd HH:mm:ss so they match the created_at column.